# R - how to print multiple MLE output as dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, output, mle

I am quite new in R and I am stack in getting a table of output values from multiple MLE running for different sample sizes.
Here is my code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)

set.seed(1234) 
#Generating Sample1 and saved in a list
n <- c(25, 50, 100, 250, 500)
mean <- 10
sd <- 1
#generate a list of list of 25 zeros, 50 zeros...
Sample1.list <- list(n25=rep(0, 25), n50=rep(0, 50), n100=rep(0, 100), n250=rep(0, 250), n500=rep(0, 500))
MLE_Sample1 <- list(rep(c(0, 0), times=length(n)))

for (i in seq_along(n)) {
  Sample1 <- rlnorm(n[i], meanlog=mean, sdlog=sd)
  Sample1.list[[i]] <- Sample1
  MLE.lnorm <- mledist(Sample1, "lnorm")
  estimate <- MLE.lnorm$estimate
  MLE_Sample1[[i]] <- estimate
}
```

Now, the list 'MLE_Sample1 contains all the MLE output (i.e. the two lognormal parameter estimates)
for each sample, and I would like to render them in a unique object as a data frame or a table, with vector names as header. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that. I tried to look at different sources here and on R-guides, but I did not find anything, which is quite strange because to me it seems to be a fundamental operation in R..
Does anyone know how to deal with that?
As always, any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a list of data.frames and then `rbindlist` them (a `data.table` function)

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(actuar)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1234) 
#Generating Sample1 and saved in a list
n <- c(25, 50, 100, 250, 500)
mean <- 10
sd <- 1
#generate a list of list of 25 zeros, 50 zeros...
Sample1.list <- list(n25=rep(0, 25), n50=rep(0, 50), n100=rep(0, 100), n250=rep(0, 250), n500=rep(0, 500))
MLE_Sample1 <- list(rep(c(0, 0), times=length(n)))


for (i in seq_along(n)) {
  Sample1 <- rlnorm(n[i], meanlog=mean, sdlog=sd)
  Sample1.list[[i]] <- Sample1
  MLE.lnorm <- mledist(Sample1, "lnorm")
  estimate <- MLE.lnorm$estimate
  MLE_Sample1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(estimate))
}
rbindlist(MLE_Sample1)

     meanlog     sdlog
1:  9.758218 0.9048491
2:  9.773453 1.0790497
3: 10.052040 0.8846443
4: 10.035170 1.0340745
5:  9.954018 0.9791639
```